# Connect to 0.0.0.0 host with a client

Tags: localhost, ip, psql

I know difference between `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` while using it in some server that listens on ip but how does it differs in context of connecting somewhere? e.g.

```
psql --host 0.0.0.0
```

vs

```
psql --host 127.0.0.1
```